# RichFaces faces-config.xml Declaration Errors

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, faces-config

I am at the throes of learning RichFaces and JSF 2.X.  I am using a tutorial [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#RegisteringRichFacesinwebxml) and Eclipse marks the faces-config declaration

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd" 
version="1.2">
```

in error

> Multiple markers at this line

- Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "faces-config".
- Attribute "xmlns" with value "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" must have a value of "http://java.sun.com/JSF/Configuration".
- Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "faces-config".
- Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" must be declared for element type "faces-config".

I know I am out of my depth here and have attempted to ascertain a fix for this.  Am I missing declarations?  Forget to include something?

Comment: It'll be easier if you will create JSF project directly in Eclipse or use maven archetypes. BTW. If you can DO NOT use RF 3.X it is deprecated from over 6 years. BTW2. Can't you tell that something is wrong if you 'are using' JSF 2.X, but adding `version="1.2"` to `faces-config`?

Comment: Basically, it's a big difference between 1.X and 2.X and there is a difference in namespace between 2.0-1.X and 2.2.X. Your problem has anything to do with RichFaces, so if you lack of the JSF's tutorials, then read documentation on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsf/916/getting-started-with-jsf#t=201611211557375127494. Adding RichFaces will be easy after.

Answer (score 1):

For JSF 2.1, `faces-config.xml` should look like below -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
          version="2.1">


    </faces-config>
```

And for JSF 2.2, `faces-config.xml` is changed -

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
            version="2.2">

       </faces-config>
```

Comment: This is true for JSF 2.1, not for 2.2.

Comment: @EmilSierżęga thanks for noticing, I just edited my answer.